# Desktop environment without greeter

Tags: x11, login, console, desktop-environment

I recently installed Arch Linux (for the first time) and now want to install a Desktop Environment.

Since I really like the *jus terminal* feel and would like to keep a non desktop environment for all users (except one). I would start this user, when I want to do graphical stuff (I won't do anything other than surfing anyway).

I also enjoy the default login of Arch Linux (e.g. just the terminal login).

Is it possible to install a desktop environment for just a specific user without a greeter? And how would I go about starting the environment automatically (but only for this *one* user)?

Comment: You can start a DE from [your ~/.xinitrc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc#Making_a_DE.2FWM_choice)...

Comment: @jasonwryan Thank you really much! When I try to install stuff with a (non-root) user. Will it affect other users as well? Or can I safely create testing-user to test DM's and if I don't like them I just remove the user?

Comment: Once you login as $USER and issue `startx`, then everything else that follows only impacts $USER. You can still use a greeter for $USER2 if that is what you want.

Comment: @jasonwryan I mean will the installation of packages in one user affect other users (in any way) as well?

Comment: The packages you install are available to *all* users on the system. I don't understand what you mean by "affect other users"... $USER can run Gnome and $USER2 can run dwm quite happily.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thank you. I think I'll just go ahead and play with it...